# Replacing Honeywell Thermostat with different wires

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am trying to replace my old Honeywell Thermostat with a new programmable one. My electric box has 4 wires (2 black and 2 white). My Thermostat has 2 wires (2 black). How should I be connecting these? Is it as si

Comment: Is this a line-voltage base board thermostat or something?  Might need a little more detail, because "thermostat" with no other details usually refers to a low voltage device for controlling an HVAC system.

Comment: What make and model is your new thermostat?